# How to implement `breakpoints` in Flutter to check the response line by line?

Tags: flutter

How to implement `breakpoints` in Flutter to check the response line by line?
I tried it with `inlinebreakpoint` which is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS Code and Android Studio you should click next to line numbers to put breakpoints. then run app in debug mode

Answer (score 2):

I think you are very new with VS Code IDE, You can add breakpoint and manage them from here,
[image]

Comment: Yes am new here. I don't know about this--> To use break point we have to run in  debug mode. AW Thank You